# Use axel in apt-fast instead of aria2

Tags: apt-fast, axel

I have installed apt-fast, but I only get aria2 downloader and nothing else. I like to use axel, and have installed it too, but I cannot use it for apt-fast.

I also tried:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure apt-fast
```

but get only aria2 as option, (and also custom option)

I want to use axel, how to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

axel support is gone with apt-fast 1.8.1 because axel does not support following features:

- multiple mirrors per file
- continuation of partly downloaded files

But if you want to use axel anyway (and make sure you don't use the `MIRRORS` option - which is disabled as default) you can simply set up the following custom command:

```
 cat "${DLLIST}" | xargs -l1 axel -n "${_MAXNUM}" -a
```

Comment: axel has some advantages, which is felt in low speed connection, as i see if there is just a single file to be downloaded, axel does it in parts, much faster than aria2, (seems aria2 doesn't download files by part, it just allows downloading multiple files at the same time)

Comment: You second point is not valid. Axel can and does resume partially finished downloads.

Comment: can anyone explain properly how to do it?